# How to have react load Home page and then route to others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, components

I have a basic portfolio app that has the following structure:

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <LeftNav />
    <RightNav />
    <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route component={Home} path='/' exact />
        <Route component={About} path='/about' />
        <Route component={Project} path='/projects' />
        <Route component={Contact} path='/contact' />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

When I click on the link to go the production site it only renders the LeftNav, RightNav, and Navbar. I have to click on the Home component to have the Home Screen load.

I then tried putting the Home component outside of  to look like:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <LeftNav />
    <RightNav />
    <NavBar />
    <Home />
      <Switch>
        <Route component={Home} path='/' exact />
        <Route component={About} path='/about' />
        <Route component={Project} path='/projects' />
        <Route component={Contact} path='/contact' />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

This is the action I want upon clicking on the link, however then my  components don't load. How do I structure this so that the Home component loads up on the initial click and that I'm able to navigate to other pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first version is good, just add a redirect and change the home path

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';  // import Redirect

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <LeftNav />
    <RightNav />
    <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route component={Home} path='/home' exact />          // change the path
        <Route component={About} path='/about' />
        <Route component={Project} path='/projects' />
        <Route component={Contact} path='/contact' />
        <Route path="/" exact>                                 // Add the redirect
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. So basically the redirect takes in the Home component and redirects it when the main URL is clicked on?

Comment: the main url "/" redirects the user to "home" and if the user clicks on "home" it will reach "home" (it makes sense)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to exchange your home path from being the default page:

```
        <Route component={Home} path='/' exact />
```

to

```
        <Route component={Home} path='/home' exact />
```

and then add a 'Redirect' to your App.js :

```
    <Route path="/" exact>                               
      <Redirect to="/home" />
    </Route>
```